# Change a UILabels text with a UISliders value

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uilabel, uislider

How I could show a UISliders value as a UILabels text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an action to the slider, like this:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Where the `sliderChanged:` method looks something like this:

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", slider.value];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {  
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];
}
```

If label and/or slider are IB elements, define IBOutlets and connect them.

And then connect the slider `sliderChanged` action to this method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is for getting the Int Value

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender 
{ 
  yourtextlabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)yourslideroutletname.value];
NSLog(@"the selider value==%@",yourtextlabel.text);
 }

//This is for getting the float Value

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender 
{ 
  yourtextlabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", yourslideroutletname.value];
NSLog(@"the selider value==%@",yourtextlabel.text);
 }
```